# String manipulation problem

Tags: string-manipulation

I have many strings of the following kind:

```
string="(Vitis_vinifera_VvNAC09_GSVIVT01009651001:1.174911034,((Musa_\
acuminata_GSMUA_Achr7T26050_001:0.1846057474,Musa_acuminata_GSMUA_\
Achr4T07148_001:0.2741664889)_D_1_0_0_9260000000_:0.2005997307,(Oryza_\
sativa_Os10g21560_1:0.9733414222,Musa_acuminata_GSMUA_Achr2T06610_001:\
0.4881902598)0_1700000000:0.0623981619)_D_0_5__:0.13917144990000008);"
```

These are trees downloaded from the public database "TreeBase". I import them as strings and I want to get rid of what officially is the node names in the Newick format.

To be precise, I want to delete everything that stands between a ")" symbol and THE NEXT ":" symbol.

For my example, I want to get the following:

```
"(Vitis_vinifera_VvNAC09_GSVIVT01009651001:1.174911034,((Musa_\
acuminata_GSMUA_Achr7T26050_001:0.1846057474,Musa_acuminata_GSMUA_\
Achr4T07148_001:0.2741664889):0.2005997307,(Oryza_\
sativa_Os10g21560_1:0.9733414222,Musa_acuminata_GSMUA_Achr2T06610_001:\
0.4881902598):0.0623981619):0.13917144990000008);"
```

However, if I do

```
StringReplace[string, ")" ~~ __ ~~ ":" -> ")"]
```

what I get is this:

```
"(Vitis_vinifera_VvNAC09_GSVIVT01009651001:1.174911034,((Musa_\
acuminata_GSMUA_Achr7T26050_001:0.1846057474,Musa_acuminata_GSMUA_\
Achr4T07148_001:0.2741664889)0.13917144990000008);"
```

I.e., Mathematica replaces everything between the first ")" symbol and the LAST ":" symbol. But that's not what I want.

Can anyone help with this please? Thanks so much!

Comment: I am not very clear on what you are trying to do, but something tells me you should toss in a `Shortest` in your string pattern. Try `StringReplace[string, Shortest[")"~~__~~":"] -> ")"]`. I get the following output: `(Vitis_vinifera_VvNAC09_GSVIVT01009651001:1.174911034,((Musa_\
acuminata_GSMUA_Achr7T26050_001:0.1846057474,Musa_acuminata_GSMUA_\
Achr4T07148_001:0.2741664889)0.2005997307,(Oryza_sativa_Os10g21560_1:\
0.9733414222,Musa_acuminata_GSMUA_Achr2T06610_001:0.4881902598)0.\
0623981619)0.13917144990000008);`

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2267680).

Comment: Or `StringReplace[string, ")" ~~ __?(StringFreeQ[#, ":"] &) ~~ ":" -> ")"]`

Comment: Is it possible to download the data in JSON format?

Comment: The [TreeBASE website](https://www.treebase.org/treebase-web/home.html) notes that all data are available in NEXUS format and the [WL documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/NEXUS.html) notes this as an available import format. Maybe it would be easier if you used the built-in import tools?

Comment: Sjoerd Smit: No, this doesn't fix the problem, because the Import tool of Nexus in Mathematica only applies to sequence data etc., not to the trees provided in Nexus format, and I am only interested in the trees. Moreover, I do not simply want to import them (which I actually do! I downloaded thousands of trees from TreeBase), but I also want to manipulate them so that they work with my code. That's why I needed an answer to my question, which has been solved now.

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for regular expressions:

```
string="(Vitis_vinifera_VvNAC09_GSVIVT01009651001:1.174911034,((Musa_
acuminata_GSMUA_Achr7T26050_001:0.1846057474,Musa_acuminata_GSMUA_
Achr4T07148_001:0.2741664889)D_1_0_0_9260000000:0.2005997307,(Oryza_
sativa_Os10g21560_1:0.9733414222,Musa_acuminata_GSMUA_Achr2T06610_001:
0.4881902598)0_1700000000:0.0623981619)D_0_5_:0.13917144990000008);"

string1="(Vitis_vinifera_VvNAC09_GSVIVT01009651001:1.174911034,((Musa_
acuminata_GSMUA_Achr7T26050_001:0.1846057474,Musa_acuminata_GSMUA_
Achr4T07148_001:0.2741664889)0.13917144990000008);"


regex = "\\).*?:";
StringReplace[s, RegularExpression[regex] -> "):"] == string1

(*True*)
```